# Merge all *.txt files in one text file whose name is given by the user using C++

Tags: c++, shell, file-io

I am trying to make a small and simple shell using c++ and i want to use something like this .

```
if (arr[0] == "type")

    {
         system("type *.txt >> output.txt");
    }
```

If the user enters type the programm will merge all the text files in the current working directory into one . When i run it with the code above it merges the files but adds the content of those text files twice to the output.txt. Also can i specify the "output.txt" with an array value i have stored ?

The way the user enters a command is like this

```
  getline(cin, command);


        string line = command;             
        string arr[5];
        int i = 0;
        stringstream ssin(line);
        while (ssin.good() && i < 5) {
            ssin >> arr[i];
            ++i;
        }
```

so i want to use the arr[3] to replace the "output.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that output.txt is also being matched by *.txt so at some point is going to write again all the content to that file. You can easily test that changing the extension of the output.txt to, for example, output.out.

For the second question you could do something like this:

```
ofstream os;
string out_file_name;
os << "type *.txt >> " << out_file_name;
system(os.str().c_str());
```

Something like that might work

Comment: Yeap totally missed that . It fixed my first problem . Do you have any idea on how should i proceed with my second problem ? Is it possible anyhow to insert a variable in the system() to change the "output.txt"?

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work . str() isn't a member of the class std::basic_ofstream

Comment: That didnt work too . But i tried this and it worked system(os.str().c_str());

Comment: The system() takes a constant char as a parameter

Comment: Oh, I though it would accept strings. I update the solution then.